# angularjs testing directive modifying user input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, directive

My directive looks like this (removes non-digits from input):

```
'use strict';

angular.module('fooApp')
  .directive('percent', function () {
    return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      function fromUser(text) {

        // get rid of non-number data
        var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

        if(transformedInput !== text) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return transformedInput;
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
    }
  };
  }
```

my test looks like this:

```
'use strict';

describe('Directive: percent', function () {

    var $compile;
    var $rootScope;

  beforeEach(module('fooApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $compile = _$compile_;
  }));

  it('Removes non-digits', function () {
    $compile('<input percent ng-model="someModel.Property" value="1a2b3"></input>')($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    console.log($rootScope.someModel);
    expect($rootScope.someModel.Property).toEqual('123');
  });
});
```

However I can see in the log:

```
LOG: undefined
```

So it sounds like `someModel` is not set => test fails.

Not sure what's wrong with my directive. If I test manually: input non-digits in HTML page, these are not shown (are ignored).

What would be the proper way to test that?

I suspect, that my directive is not modifying stuff once data don't come from user but are set via value. Not sure however how to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is to use the modelController `$setViewValue(value)` to trigger your parser pipeline. To get hold of the modelcontroller, you would have to wrap the dummy html in a `form`:

```
  $compile('<form name="form1"><input percent ng-model="someModel.Property" name='data'></input></form>')($rootScope);
  $rootScope.form1.data.$setViewValue('1a2b3')
  $rootScope.$digest();
  console.log($rootScope.someModel);
  expect($rootScope.someModel.Property).toEqual('123');
```

Can you give it a try.